# "Read More" link, in an HTML Newsletter

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, newsletter

I want to insert in my HTML newsletter a link "Read more ... " that expand/hide my news inside of my email with more info (more text). How can I do this to work on Microsoft Outlook.

I know how to do that on a web page using CSS (code mentioned below) but on an email this doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<p class="read-more-wrap">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
    <span class="read-more-target">hidden lorem ipsum hidden lorem ipsum hidden lorem ipsum hidden lorem ipsum hidden lorem ipsum.</span>
</p>
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
```

CSS:

```
.read-more-state {
    display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
    max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
    content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    color: #666;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 2;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Comment: You can't achieve what you want in Outlook. Probably neither in the latest email client without an "hackish" workaround

Answer (score 3):

Here is the easiest solution I could think of:

CSS:

```
#mycheckbox:checked ~ .moretext {
  display: block;
}

.moretext{
  display: none;
}

#mycheckbox{
  display: none;
}
.showmore{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore">Toggle more</label>
<div class="moretext" >Some more text</div>
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/behxbd0t/**

Comment: I just used this and it worked perfectly for what I'm trying to do. My only question is the 'Toggle More' Text is bold.. how do I make it normal? Thanks!

Comment: use `font-weight: normal;` on the class `showmore`.

Comment: How do I do that? I changed it to the following but it doesn't work. Thanks! - <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<label for="mycheckbox" class="showmore" font-weight: normal;>Read More...</label>
<div class="moretext" >

Comment: Add the mentioned line in css?

Comment: I tried putting it in here and it still doesn't work - @media (min-width: 1000px) {
.textcontainer{
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
font-weight: normal;
width: 900px
}
}